# Read and write json files to server with flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I need a json file on the server to store some data, but it won't be too big to need a database. So I try to read the file, and after I finish using it I will need to overwrite the data to keep update.
I tried like this:

```
@app.route("/json")
def readwrite():
    SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    json_url = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT,'static', 'test.json')
    token = open(json_url)
    return token
```

But I get a 404 error on those. I'm not sure how I can read out those data and further rewrite. Please help if you see any problem in my code. Thanks!

Comment: To check that your flask app is running on a server you can access, return "jibberish" and access http://example.com/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the file handle via HTTP to the client. Get the json data and send that.

```
stored_json = token.readlines()
token.close()
return stored_json
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I searched online for answer, and found those example works perfectly on my local. But when I use that for my application hosting online, it doesn't really work. I tried yours and it still gave me 404 error. Any idea?

Comment: What happens when you `return "test"`? I suspect you aren't launching your flask app on your server at all.

Comment: You have to do things a little differently when deploying on a server. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#public-server and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#deploying-to-a-web-server

Comment: I did. If it's a simple string, it does show up on the page.

Comment: OK. What does your `test.json` file look like? `readlines()` returns a list of strings and I should have suggested to return `stored_json[0]`.

Comment: It's a list, and I do try to return the first item, but the result is the same. I'm really confused by this fact. Those works under python should work under flask right? But it doesn't operate like that on my server. Any other thought I might do it wrong? Anyway thank you for your ideas!

Comment: its jus bcd of the permission.. Sorry for confusing you. I'm too new on this lol